# need to set a data-* with no value with vanilla js

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

i'm creating a list of links dinamically from the sections i have:

```
$sections.forEach(({ id, firstElementChild: { textContent } }) => {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.classList.add('link');
    link.setAttribute('href', `#${id}`);
    link.setAttribute('data-scroll-spy', true);
    link.textContent = textContent;
    fragment.appendChild(link);
```

i need to put a data-scroll-spy to each of thems, but with NO value.
i need to have receive this:

```
<a class="link" href="#" data-scroll-spy>some text</a>
```

the only solution i ve found by far is with setAttribute but it is not what i expect to,

Comment: The value of a `data-XXX` attribute is a string, not a boolean.

Comment: `link.dataset.spy = ''` to set it to the empty string.

Comment: @Barmar  it's  `link.dataset.scrollSpy = ''`,   dataset converts camelCase to snakeCase...

Comment: Right, I just didn't see the other word, i thought it was `data-spy`

Answer (score 1):

[`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) takes a string as a second argument, not a boolean.

Set the value to an empty string rather than a boolean and you will achieve your desired result. `link.setAttribute('data-scroll-spy', '')`